# Set ImageView Drawable programmatically

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to set the image of a ImageView programmatically from a array of drawables but keep getting a NUllPointerException....does this method look correct for setting Image resource..

```
//get a random drawable
int[] imageSelection= {R.drawable.buddycheck, R.drawable.logdive3, R.drawable.sea, R.drawable.weather, R.drawable.logo1};
Random whichImage = new Random();
int theImage = whichImage.nextInt(imageSelection.length);

displayImage.setBackgroundResource(theImage);
```

Comment: Where and how do you initialize displayImage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the image resource to a random number.
You need to do it like this:

```
int theImage = imageSelection[whichImage.nextInt(imageSelection.length)];
displayImage.setBackgroundResource(theImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);`